# How to make an https version of a Unirest example

Tags: node.js

I would like to use the https library in node.js to send a request to this api:
https://rapidapi.com/dimas/api/NasaAPI?endpoint=apiendpoint_b4e69440-f966-11e7-809f-87f99bda0814getPictureOfTheDay

The given example on the RapidAPI website uses Unirest, and I would like to only use the https library. I've tried to write it like this:

```
const https = require('https');

var link = "https://NasaAPIdimasV1.p.rapidapi.com/getPictureOfTheDay";
var options = {host: "https://NasaAPIdimasV1.p.rapidapi.com/getPictureOfTheDay",
path: "/", headers: {"X-RapidAPI-Key": "---MY KEY(Yes, I've replaced it)---", "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}}

https.get(link, options, (resp) => {
    let data = '';
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
    });
    resp.on('end', () => {
        console.log(data);
    });
}).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("https error 4: " + err.message);
});
```

But that returns the following response:

```
{"message":"Endpoint\/ does not exist"}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why do you specify your link twice - once in `link`, then in `host` and `path` props of `options`? Drop the latter

Comment: I specified it twice because I have no experience in using the library, and don't know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes.

First, you essentially pass URL in `https` twice - first as `link` param, second as combination of `host` and `path` properties for `options` param.

Second, your `host` is actually the full path - but it shouldn't be. In the end, looks like the library got confused and sent request to `https://NasaAPIdimasV1.p.rapidapi.com/` instead.

Finally, this particular API requires using 'POST', not 'GET' method. That's actually mentioned in the documentation. That's why you have 'endpoint does not exist' error even on correctly formed request.

One possible approach is dropping `link` altogether, sending URL as part of `options`:

```
var options = {
  host: 'NasaAPIdimasV1.p.rapidapi.com',
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/getPictureOfTheDay', 
  headers: {/* the same */}
};
https.request(options, (resp) => { /* the same */ }).end();
```

Comment: When I tried this it did this: 
https error 4: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://NasaAPIdimasV1.p.rapidapi.com https://NasaAPIdimasV1.p.rapidapi.com:443

Comment: Yes, because API uses 'POST' on every request, not 'GET'; the documentation is actually quite clear on that. Updated my answer.